# F# System.TypeLoadException

Tags: f#, mono, visual-studio-code, typeloadexception

by this code

```
module ObjectRe =
  type BM = A | N
  type Object = {
    Name: string
    Pattern: BM array
  }

  let patterns = [|{Name = "Pro"; Pattern = [|A;N;N;A|]} |]
```

I always get this error message

```
System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'FSI_0007+ObjectRe+Object[]' from assembly 'FSI-ASSEMBLY, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.
  at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoMethod:InternalInvoke (System.Reflection.MonoMethod,object,object[],System.Exception&)
  at System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, System.Reflection.BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00038] in <94fd79a3b7144c54b4cb162b50fc7761>:0 
Stopped due to error
```

Has anyone an idea? I use Visual Studio Code on Mac.

Thanks

Comment: It seems like you missed closing `|]` at the end of patterns definition.

Comment: Sorry I forgot it during copying :/ that's not the problem

Comment: FWIW, the above code runs without problems in Visual Studio 2015 on Windows 10, so it may be an environment-related problem.

Comment: Okay that's a good and bad message. Thank you for the information. I hope anyone has an idea to fix it :)

Comment: I can't reproduce this either, but I'm also on Windows/.NET/VS2015. You may want to add a mono tag and specify in more detail what environment you're using. Does the error remain if you change the type's name from `Object`? That's a very unusual name for a user-defined CLI type, since every type derives from System.Object, which is mentioned in the error message too.

Comment: I also can't reproduce this error and I run it from mono on Linux. Maybe you should check, that there are no tabs anywhere. Or maybe something wrong with fsharpi or mono

Comment: Yes object is a really unusual name. I changed but I get the same error. I tested it with xamarin for mac and there are no problems.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can also reproduce this on macOS 10.11, mono 4.6.

**The minimal reproduction is :**

```
module X =
    type Y = Y
    let l = [| Y |]
```

**With a workaround** :

```
module X =
    type Y = Y
    let g = List.toArray [ Y ]
```

So in your case replace **both** the *inner* and the *outer* `[| |]` declarations.

**Why this happens only in VS Code/fsharpi but not in Xamarin?**

If you fire up activity monitor you will see that VS Code/fsharpi uses the
`/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.6.0/lib/mono/4.5/fsi.exe` binary, but Xamarin Studio uses the FCS `Xamarin Studio.app/Contents/Resources/lib/monodevelop/AddIns/BackendBindings/MonoDevelop.FSharpInteractive.Service.exe` You can check also the version on the first message from the interactive (`F# Interactive for F# 4.1`, those might be different).

Finally, i believe this is a bug on mono + dynamic assemblies, triggered by the code emitted by the `fsi`. Compiling this code to an `exe` works fine on all platforms (and if you check the generated IL seems pretty normal).